# Differentials injectiveness in the definition of an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently studying differential geometry and read about immersions. I have the following definition:

A map $f\in C^\infty(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ from an open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is called an immersion if for all $x\in U$ the differential $\mathrm{d}_xf:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is injective.

However, I don't quite understand, what the injectiveness of the differential intuitively contributes to the definition. Of course, without it, the definition would just be a smooth map. Still, could someone give an example, where a map would almost be an immersion in the intuitive sense but falls short at some point? I am just searching for some intuition on the topic.

Comment: The map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2:t\mapsto(t^2,t^3)$ is smooth, but it's not an immersion because its differential is zero at the origin. Draw a graph of this parametrized curve in $\mathbb R^2$ to see why that makes us unhappy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Consider
$$
t \mapsto (t^3, t^9)
$$
whose image looks exactly like the graph of $y = x^3$, which you'd think would be not just an immersion, but an *embedding*. So what's the problem? At $t = 0$, the derivative of this map is $v \mapsto (0, 0)$, where $v$ is an arbitrary vector in the tangent space to $\mathbb R$ at $0$.

Of course, in this case, the image  --- that "apparent graph" --- actually *is* the image of an immersion, namely, the immersion $t \mapsto (t, t^3)$, whose derivative is everywhere nonzero.

Now let's slightly modify things, and let
$$
\gamma(t) = (|t^3|, t^9)
$$
It takes a little work, but you can check that this $gamma$ also $C^1$-smooth. But at $\gamma(0)$ the image has a sharp "point"  which isn't at all what you want in an immersion.

If we tried to "break" $t \mapsto (t, t^3)$ in the same way, we'd get
$$
t \mapsto (|t|, t^3)
$$
which is not differentiable at $t = 0$, so this "trick" doesn't work (i.e., the definition of immersion seems to be protecting us against things we don't want to call immersions).

By the way, when you learn about regular homotopy of immersions (e.g., reading Whitney's paper on the Whitney-Graustein theorem), there's a similar technical point in the definition of regular homotopy that you should try to understand as well.